# Clase derivada carece de método público de la clase padre (ambas hacen uso de plantillas)

Tags: c++, herencia, template

el problema seguramente sea algo muy simple de resolver pero no acabo de verlo...

Tengo unas clases llamadas Container y List. La segunda es hija de la primera y ambas hacen uso de plantillas.

En la primera tengo un método llamado AddItem que acepta un objeto de tipo T por valor, y en la segunda tengo otro AddItem que acepta un puntero a un objeto del mismo tipo.

Pues por alguna razón que se me escapa, si intento esto:

```
List<int> container = List<int>();
container.AddItem (5);
```

Obtengo el siguiente error de G++:
"invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]"

Y es porque, obviamente, está llamando al método AddItem de List, que pide un puntero, en lugar de llamar al AddItem de Container.

Todo esto me funcionaba antes bien sin usar herencia, pero he querido ponerlo así y ahora me he tropezado con éste problema.

Aquí las 2 clases:

**AriLibs_Container.h**

```
#if !defined (__ARILIBS_CONTAINER__)
#define __ARILIBS_CONTAINER__

#if !defined (nullptr)
#define nullptr NULL
#endif

#include "AriLibs_FunctionPointers.h"

namespace AriLibs
{
    template <class T>
class Container
{
    protected:
        int size = 0;

    public:
        Container () {}
        virtual ~Container () {}

        virtual void AddItem (T* item) = 0;
        void AddItem (T item);
        void AddRange (T* array, int arraySize);
        void AddRange (T& array, int arraySize);
        virtual bool Contains (T* item, bool clearItem = false) = 0;
        bool Contains (T item);
        virtual int IndexOf (T* item, bool clearItem = false) { return -1; }
        int IndexOf (T item);
        int IsEmpty ();
        virtual void ForEachItem (Func1_Ptr<T> func) = 0;            
        int Size ();
};


template <class T>
void Container<T>::AddItem (T item)
{
    T* itemPtr = new T (item);
    this->AddItem (itemPtr);
}


template <class T>
void Container<T>::AddRange (T* array, int arraySize)
{
    if (array != nullptr)
    {
        for (int item = 0; item < arraySize; item ++)
        {
            this->AddItem (array[item]);
        }
    }
}


template <class T>
void Container<T>::AddRange (T& array, int arraySize)
{
    for (int item = 0; item < arraySize; item ++)
    {
        this->AddItem (array[item]);
    }
}


template <class T>
bool Container<T>::Contains (T item)
{
    T* itemPtr = new T (item);
    return this->Contains (itemPtr, true);
}


template <class T>
int Container<T>::IndexOf (T item)
{
    T* itemPtr = new T (item);
    return this->IndexOf (itemPtr, true);
}


template <class T>
int Container<T>::IsEmpty ()
{
    return (this->size == 0);
}


template <class T>
int Container<T>::Size ()
{
    return this->size;
}
}

#endif
```

**AriLibs_List.h**

```
#if !defined (__ARILIBS_LIST__)
#define __ARILIBS_LIST__

#if !defined (nullptr)
#define nullptr NULL
#endif

#if !defined (Arduino_h)
#include <vector>
#endif

#include "AriLibs_Container.h"
#include "AriLibs_FunctionPointers.h"

namespace AriLibs
{
template <class T>
class List : public Container<T>
{
    public:
        void AddItem (T* item) override;
        bool Contains (T* item, bool clearItem = false) override;
        int IndexOf (T* item, bool clearItem = false) override;
        void ForEachItem (Func1_Ptr<T> func) override;
};


template <class T>
void List<T>::AddItem (T* item)
{
    
}


template <class T>
bool List<T>::Contains (T* item, bool clearItem)
{
    return false;
}


template <class T>
int List<T>::IndexOf (T* item, bool clearItem)
{
    return -1;
}


template <class T>
void List<T>::ForEachItem (Func1_Ptr<T> func)
{
    
}
}

#endif
```

La clase List es un mero esbozo que he escrito para depurar.

Muchas gracias por adelantado :) .

P.D: Se que la STL tiene ya contenedores, pero estoy planificando proyectos para Arduino y decidí crear yo mis propios contenedores en lugar de mirar como alternativa un port pesado de toda la STL.

P.D 2: Sé que podría ahorrarme el duplicar los métodos y aceptar solo punteros, por ejemplo, pero he preferido hacerlo así para aceptar también datos por valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabas de descubrir una característica de C++: la ocultación de nombres (*name hiding*):

Si una función-miembro de una clase derivada tiene **el mismo nombre** que una función en la clase base, está última queda *oculta* por la primera.

Observa que no se hace referencia a los argumentos; basta con que el nombre coincida, independientemente de los argumentos de las funciones:

```
struct A {
  void algo( ) { }
};

struct B : public A {
  void algo( int ) { }
};

int main( ) {
  B b;

  b.algo( );

  return 0;
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to `B::algo( )`

Esto es así adrede; se busca no obtener comportamientos inesperados al, por error, llamar a la versión *no deseada* de la función.

Puedes resolverlo *importando* el nombre original de la clase base:

```
struct B : public A {
  using A::algo;  // <-- AQUÍ
  void algo( int ) { }
};
```

O, en tu caso y usando `template< >`:

```
class List : public Container<T>
{
    public:
        using Container< T >::AddItem;

        void AddItem (T* item) override;
        bool Contains (T* item, bool clearItem = false) override;
        int IndexOf (T* item, bool clearItem = false) override;
        void ForEachItem (Func1_Ptr<T> func) override;
};
```